# Framebuffer texture coming out white (fragment shader doesn't affect it)

Tags: c++, glsl, textures, framebuffer

So I have an fbo and trying to output a depth texture from the light source perspective. Unfortunately the depth texture is coming out pure white even if I hard code black in the frag shader.

This is my frame buffer initialization

```
//Render frame to a texture
m_FrameBuffer = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_FrameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_FrameBuffer); // once frame buffer is bound, must draw to it or black screen
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glGenTextures(1, &m_depthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_depthTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);

glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, m_depthTexture, 0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
//Always check that our framebuffer is ok
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    printf("frame buffer binding error");

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

this is my rendering of frame buffer

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_FrameBuffer);
glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 1024);

glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

This is my fragment shader

```
#version 330 core
// Ouput data
layout(location = 0) out float fragmentdepth;
void main()
{
//fragmentdepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
fragmentdepth = 0;
}
```

This is my main loop

```
while (!window.closed())
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    window.clear();

    CameraControls();
    depth.enable();

    //depthMVP = depthProjectionMatrix * depthViewMatrix * depthModelMatrix;
    depth.setUniformMat4("projection", projection);
    depth.setUniformMat4("view", camera);
    depth.setUniformMat4("model", shape1->modelMatrix);     

    shape1->RenderToTexture();
    depth.disable();
    window.clear();
    basic.enable();
    basic.setUniformMat4("proj", projection);
    //basic.setUniform3f("light_Pos", lightPos);
    basic.setUniformMat4("view", camera);
    basic.setUniformMat4("model", shape1->modelMatrix);
    basic.setUniformMat4("DepthBiasMVP", biasMatrix); 

    //NEED TO CHANGE THIS TO BIAS MATRIX X DEPTHMVP
    //MVP = projection * camera * shape1->modelMatrix;
    //basic.setUniformMat4("MVP", MVP);
    shape1->Render(basic);
    basic.disable();
    window.update();
}
```

I am following this tutorial http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/

Comment: Following the specifications on - https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml, my best guess is your two lines,
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);
Causing the result of rendering to the texture to be either 0 or 1

Comment: It is hard to debug opengl code due to how many places where it could go wrong. Every step of setting the state machine in opengl has to be correct. You may be rendering the framebuffer incorrectly, facing the camera the wrong way, having a depth value that is indistinguishable due to the exponential nature of perspective projection, setting rendering states incorrectly in other parts of the program, rendering the object too small... the list goes on, but you get my point.

Answer (score 0):

Just answering my own question after looking at my old questions that weren't resolved. If anyone is wondering, my problem was that I had fused two tutorials into one and one of them had different near and far values for the frustum. The framebuffer was black because the object was too far from the camera.